# Google Maps Distance Matrix API returns different output compared to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am tinkering with Google Maps APIs using web services and noticed, that I get different output from Google Maps Distance Matrix API compared to Google Maps.

This is what I mean:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Batilly&destinations=Cherbourg&language=en&key=AIzaSyAtYy7eYoooIzYGvFl15xRP2xHAdMU0-1c

this is what my query returns:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Cherbourg, France" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Batilly, France" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "195 km",
                  "value" : 194751
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "2 hours 3 mins",
                  "value" : 7373
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

And this is what Google Map returns:
[image]

So instead of 708 kilometers I get 195 kilometers. The problem is with Batilly city. Cherbourg coordinates are good.

[Real Coordingates of Batilly are 49.171029, 5.969359(Google Maps output)](https://www.google.lt/maps/place/Batilly,+France/@49.0382838,4.6012942,7.21z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x4794d5d202594c41:0x40a5fb99a3b0b20)
[Google Maps Geocoding returns 48.7486861, -0.14727](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Batilly&key=AIzaSyAtYy7eYoooIzYGvFl15xRP2xHAdMU0-1c)

**How should I configure my Google Maps Distance Matrix API so it would return the same output as Google maps does ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There obviously are more than 1 city named Batilly in france.

To get a result similar to Google Maps you may:

1. get the location via a [Places-TextSearch](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=de#TextSearchRequests).
   For me it returns the desired location(49.1710200,5.9693580)
2. use this location in the DistanceMatrix- request

Comment: He may also add the name of the "Departement", here for his "real" location it is "Meurthe-et-Moselle", and it will redirect to the right `Batilly`: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Batilly,%20Meurthe-et-Moselle&destinations=Cherbourg&language=en&key=AIzaSyAtYy7eYoooIzYGvFl15xRP2xHAdMU0-1c

Or the postcode

Comment: Really weird, the geocoder returns one result for "Batilly", as does the Place Search, but [they are different (by a 520 km drive)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Batilly&geocode=1&addr2=Batilly&place=2)